# Getting exception "object already in table" while trying to open pdf with pdfsharp library

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I am using pdfsharp library to create pdf and merge multiple pdf.

I am getting exception when trying to open pdf with below code snippet.

Using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream (file.byteContent)
PdfDocument pdf = PdfReader.Open(ms, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)

Comment: While opening the pdf itself with PdfReaer.Open(ms, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import) getting error. Merging the pdf is next step here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Each object in a PDF file has a number - and this number should be unique.
Sometimes files are corrupt and contain several objects with the same number.

Try opening and saving the PDF file with Adobe Reader - in many cases this will repair the corrupted file and PDFsharp will be able to open it.

This is just a wild guess as I do not have the PDF file in question for examination.